# Error when i deploye OVA in my ESX

Tags: vmware, esx, vsphere

I get this error when I try to deploy my OVA into my ESX:

[image: screenshot]

line 33:

```
 <System>
   <vssd:ElementName>Virtual Hardware Family</vssd:ElementName>
   <vssd:InstanceID>0</vssd:InstanceID>
   <vssd:VirtualSystemIdentifier>PF9SOSNA1</vssd:VirtualSystemIdentifier>
   <vssd:VirtualSystemType>vmx-09</vssd:VirtualSystemType>
 </System>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vmx-09 is only compatible with vSphere5 or Workstation8 - but chances are it will work on an older host with a small edit to the ovf file.

Edit the ovf file (in any text editor - eg WordPad).  Replace vmx-09 with vmx-07.  Close and save.

However when you now run the ovftool to import, you will get an error "SHA1 digest of file xxxx.ovf does not match manifest".

You can work around this by simply deleting or renaming the manifest file - the ovftool will give a warning to say no manifest file, but will continue to import the VM.  I used the import command given at the top of the thread -

Answer (score 1):

Steps to clear this error:

1. Extract the required .ova file and there will be .ovf and .mf files created post extraction.
2. Edit the .ovf file by changing vmx-09 to vmx-7 after opening it in the text mode and save the changes.
3. Delete the .mf file.
4. Open .ovf file with VMWare workstation.
5. ide0 error not detected by VM's, so select "No" while switching ON the machine on VM ware.

Answer (score 0):

You can change in your original virtual machine (before exporting as OVA), in VMX file the item `<<virtualHW.version = "10">>` into `<<virtualHW.version = "7">>`. After that export as OVA and deploy your OVA on the ESX. It worked in my case for a machine created in VMPLAYER as VMX. It was impossible to deploy it on ESX without this trick.